# MySQL query to replace null values with string when using double left outer joins

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named as `Table1, Table2, Table3`.

1. Table1 has three coloumns. They are `studentId, studentName, taskName`.
2. Table2 has two coloumns as `Id` and `student name`. Table3 includes name of students who are not taking a certain module.
3. Table3 contains two coloumns assigning each tasks to a `supervisor`. More than one task can be assigned under a supervisor.

Here I am using following query to count the number of tasks per supervisor:

```
SELECT Table3.supervisor, COUNT(*) as Total 
FROM issues 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 ON Table1.studentName=Table2.studentName 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON
     Table1.taskName=Table3.taskName 
WHERE Table2.userId is null 
GROUP BY Table3.supervior
```

Now, I need to change `supervisor-1` name into `supervisor-2` and get count for `supervisor-2` as (number of tasks for supervisor-1 + number of tasks for supervisor-2).

Can some one help to write a query?
(I have created a similar scenario of my current requirement)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.
It can by done by passing above mentioned query as inner query to sum() function.
Note : When we use output of a query as input to another query, we should name it and pass.